# Export react component into pdf and download it automatically

Tags: reactjs, jspdf, html2canvas, export-to-pdf, react-to-pdf

I am using react-to-pdf (or jsPdf, html2canvas) library to achieve my task.

```
const ExportPDF = () => {
    const ref = useRef();

    const convertToPdf = async () => {
        const pdf = new jsPDF();
        const canvas = await html2canvas(ref.current);
        const imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
        pdf.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 0, 0);
        pdf.save('ExportPDF.pdf');
    };

    return (
        <div>
            {/* <ReactToPdf targetRef={ref} filename="mypdf.pdf">
                {({ toPdf }) => (
                    <Button variant="contained" color="secondary" onClick={toPdf}>Export PDF</Button>
                )}
            </ReactToPdf> */}
            <Button variant="contained" color="secondary" onClick={convertToPdf}>Export PDF</Button>
            <div style={{ position: 'absolute', left: '-9999px' }}>
                <div style={{ display: 'none' }} ref={ref} >
                    <MyComponent />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

function MyComponent () {
    return (
        <div>
            {/* <Typography variant="h4">My PDF Document</Typography>
            <Typography variant="body1">This is some sample text.</Typography>
            <Button variant="contained" color="primary">
                Click Me!
            </Button> */}
            <h1>Hello World!</h1>
            <p>This is my existing React component.</p>
        </div>
    );
}

export default ExportPDF;
```

`myComponent` is my react component that I want to export. It contains multiple MUI components in it (ex: commented code).

In `ExportPDF`, with react-to-pdf library, I am using `<ReactToPdf>` to achieve my task. But it is throwing `invalid arguments passed to jsPdf.scale` error. Also I tried to achieve my task with simple component and with `jsPdf` and `html2canvas` libraries. But itis throwing `Incomplete or corrupt PNG file` error.

Kindly guide me to solve this error and complete the implementation. Any help is appreciated.